# print all possible paths of matrix in gofer functional programming language

Tags: functional-programming

Print all possible paths from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix

The problem is to print all the possible paths from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix with the constraints that from each cell you can either move only to right or down.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

To find all the paths from (k,l) to (m,n), use recursion.

- find all the paths from (k, l+1) to (m,n); add (k,l) to the front of each one.
- find all the paths from (k+1, l) to (m,n); add (k,l) to the front of each one.
- the paths from (m,n) to (m,n) is `[]`.

Add handling of the boundaries.

You do not need to store a matrix in any form.